# How to get "Last Modified" property for Directory in Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to understand the Azure blob storage service for managing directories. How to get the last modified date for Azure **directory**(CloudBlobDirectory). I don't find any simple answer which simply states whether this case is achievable or not.

I also have tried to get this last modified property for **Directory**, but it always returns **null**.

Similar to below code sample

```
(CloudBlobDirectory)item.Properties.LastModified.Value.LocalDateTime
```

I am expecting to maintain the last modified for directories as like windows directory.

Please, let me know how to get the last modified date for Azure directory or how can i achieve the same as like windows???

> I am trying to achieve this in ASP.NET Core application (C#)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the new package from Microsoft **Azure.Storage.Blobs** (12.X.X)
Here are examples for getting the Last Modified property for a container and blob.

```
    //using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
    //using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

    private static void GetContainerLastModified()
    {
        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, "container1");

        BlobContainerProperties properties = container.GetProperties();

        Console.WriteLine(properties.LastModified);
    }

    private static void GetBlobLastModified()
    {
        BlobClient blob = new BlobClient(connectionString, "container1", "file1.txt");

        BlobProperties properties = blob.GetProperties();

        Console.WriteLine(properties.LastModified);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, [Azure Blob Storage structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#object-model) is as follows

- You connect to a storage account
- Storage account has zero or more containers
- each container has zero or more blobs

Unlike files in your Windows filesystem, blob names can have `/` characters in it, giving you the impression of directories.

The API lets you work with it like there are subfolders, letting you list blobs that start with `something/` but are not really folders in blob storage.

So it doesn't make sense to ask for any metadata property of a `CloudBlobDirectory` as they don't really exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @madushan , I was aware of this information that we cannot have metadata property for CloudBlobDirectory. But i was curious to know is their any workaround solution exist to keep last modified date for directories???  For eg, by tracking last modified date from last created file within that folder??

Comment: Yea. You could list the blobs in that "folder" then look for the last modified one. Though this is multiple requests so it will be significantly slower.